# filesystem directory_iterator not returning full file path

Tags: c++

EDIT: I'm using std::tr2::sys not boost's filesytem

I'm working on a simple app that scans directories on the computer and returns statistics about those files. There are two ways that scan can be called: recursively and non-recursively. A path is passed into the scan method along with a flag for whether or not the scan should be done recursively. Given the `path folder` the two implementations look something like this:

```
directory_iterator start( folder ), end;
for( ; start != end; ++start ) {
    //Some code in here
    // get the path like this:
    auto path = start->path();
}
```

or

```
recursive_directory_iterator start( folder ), end;
for( ; start != end; ++start ) {
    //Some code in here
    // get the path like this:
    auto path = start->path();
}
```

The problem I'm encountering is that in the block that uses the regular directory_iterator when I try and grab the path it will return only the file name ie. "myTextFile.txt" where as getting it from the recursive_directory_iterator returns the full path to the file on the system. In each case the value of folder is the same (a full file path as well). Is there a reason the front part of the path is getting chopped off or is there some way I can get the full file path from just the abbreviated one that I'm getting back from directory_iterator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [complete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh874892.aspx) function:

```
auto full_path = std::tr2::sys::complete(path, folder);
```

Another simple way to do it would be be to simply append the filename to the path (tested on MSVC2012 with the `<filesystem>` in the `std::tr2::sys` namespace):

```
for (; start != end; ++start) {
    auto path = start->path();
    auto full_path = folder / path;
}
```

Comment: @JesseCarter: Interestingly, `boost::filesystem` gives you the full path with `start->path();`, but microsoft's implementation does not.

Answer (score 2):

For full path you need to use `start->path().directory_string()`

```
directory_iterator end;
for (directory_iterator start(p);
      start != end;
      ++start)
{
    if (is_directory(start->status()))
    {
      //A directory
    }
    if (is_regular_file(start->status()))
    {   
      std::cout << start->path().directory_string()<< "\n";
    }
}
```

Play around with following based on your need, refer boost docs for more details, however names their suggest all.

```
start->path().branch_path();
start->path().directory_string();
start->path().file_string();
start->path().root_path();
start->path().parent_path();
start->path().string();
start->path().basename();
start->path().filename();
start->path().root_name();
start->path().relative_path();
```

Comment: This isn't working, I tried using directory_string and it is still just returning the name of the file without any path in front of it

Comment: Boost 1.72, only some functions worked but this is what did

`std::cout << i->path().branch_path() << std::endl;    // "/path/to/data"`

`std::cout << i->path().root_path() << std::endl;      // "/"`

`std::cout << i->path().parent_path() << std::endl;    // "/path/to/data"`

`std::cout << i->path().string() << std::endl;         // "/path/to/data/file.txt"`

`std::cout << i->path().filename() << std::endl;       // "file.txt"`

`std::cout << i->path().root_name() << std::endl;      // ""`

`std::cout << i->path().relative_path() << std::endl;  // "/path/to/data/file.txt"``